# R: dcast inside a function does not find passed variable

Tags: r, function, variables, get, dcast

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
> mydata <- data.frame(gene=rep(paste(sample(LETTERS, 10, replace=TRUE), sample(1:1000, 10, replace=FALSE), sep=''), each=5),
+                    clus=rep(sample(c('clus1','clus2'),10,replace=TRUE), each=5),
+                    treat=rep(LETTERS[1:5],10),
+                    value=rnorm(n=50))
> head(mydata,10)
   gene  clus treat       value
1   R22 clus2     A -0.25592597
2   R22 clus2     B  0.02956595
3   R22 clus2     C  0.36785764
4   R22 clus2     D -1.47393076
5   R22 clus2     E -2.09895513
6  S671 clus2     A -0.17079390
7  S671 clus2     B  1.73643010
8  S671 clus2     C  0.73169650
9  S671 clus2     D -0.85247328
10 S671 clus2     E  1.43589407
```

I have a general function in which the first step is `dcast` a `data.frame` like that in this way:

```
> dcast(mydata, gene+clus~treat, value.var="value")
   gene  clus          A           B            C          D           E
1  B957 clus1 -2.0567334  2.27900277  0.714784782  2.5123012 -0.91194409
2   I55 clus2 -1.3044907 -1.06102427 -0.380294765 -0.1194413  1.90913241
3  M937 clus1 -2.1610684  1.82269937  0.716722593 -0.1525909  0.92291856
4  N986 clus1  0.2483086 -0.41405923 -0.714040214 -0.4243231  0.13645697
5   R22 clus2 -0.2559260  0.02956595  0.367857644 -1.4739308 -2.09895513
6  R295 clus2 -0.4673256  0.08302997 -0.352803402  0.2983689  1.25420084
7  R545 clus1  2.5655384 -0.14798670  1.001409732  0.1971712 -0.11440350
8  S671 clus2 -0.1707939  1.73643010  0.731696498 -0.8524733  1.43589407
9  W131 clus1  0.9915700  0.05430845  0.008878675 -1.7140515  0.06019417
10 Z302 clus1  1.2854086  0.09809435 -2.533077634 -1.0244764 -0.57606345
```

While this works outside a function, it does not seem to work inside... I have this minimal function:

```
myfun <- function(mydf, groupvar, groupvar2, measurevar, valuevar){
    newdf <- dcast(mydf, get(measurevar)+get(groupvar2)~get(groupvar), value.var=valuevar)#cannot change sep from "_"
}
```

But when I call it, I get the following error:

```
> myfun(mydata, "treat", "clus", "gene", "value")
```

> Error in get(measurevar) : object 'measurevar' not found

Why doesn't my function find the variable `measurevar` I pass?

However, if I `return` it before `dcast`, it returns it with no problem, and `dcast` all of a sudden works:

```
> myfun <- function(mydf, groupvar, groupvar2, measurevar, valuevar){
+     return(list(groupvar,groupvar2,measurevar,valuevar))
+     newdf <- dcast(mydf, get(measurevar)+get(groupvar2)~get(groupvar), value.var=valuevar)#cannot change sep from "_"
+ }
> myfun(mydata, "treat", "clus", "gene", "value")
[[1]]
[1] "treat"

[[2]]
[1] "clus"

[[3]]
[1] "gene"

[[4]]
[1] "value"
```

What is going on here? I really do not understand anything... Why doesn't `dcast` find the variable `measurevar` I pass, but if I return it first, it all of a sudden does??

Thanks!

Comment: check out `as.formula(paste(measurevar, "+", groupvar2, "~", groupvar))`

Comment: OK this works, by is there a reason why `get()` does not?

Comment: `get(measurevar)+get(groupvar2)~get(groupvar)` does not eval to `measurevar + groupvar2 ~ groupvar`. dcast is expecting measurevar + groupvar2 ~ groupvar in the 2nd argument

Comment: I don't really understand that... you want to develop this into an answer?